# Jquery. Работа с z-index

Tags: jquery, css

Добрый день!

Имеем такую структуру:

```
<div class="header-wrap">
  <header></header>
  <div class="video"></div>
</div>
<div class="content"></div>
```

При скролле страницы, для **<header**> добавляем класс **header-scroll** (position: fixed;).

Необходимо, при scrollTop > 112, для header **задать z-index** меньше чем у родителя (.header-wrap).

В конечном итоге, должны получить header, "выезжающий" из под родителя (.header-wrap).

**[Ссылка на jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/Pzh9X/)**

Comment: Боюсь это не получится при такой структуре. z-index не так прост, как кажется.

Comment: @psyсho_Octopus , спасибо конечно, что "убили" надежду ...:)

Может кто-нибудь все-таки сталкивался с чем-либо подобным?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно попробовать [такой](http://jsfiddle.net/Pzh9X/) вариант. Минус в отрицательном z-index'е.

Comment: Это тот же вариант, что и у меня

Comment: Прошу прощения, забыл сохранить обновления. Вот рабочий:
http://jsfiddle.net/Pzh9X/1/

Comment: @Genson, спасибо.